# long section titles with reledpar

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

Typesetting section-titles that flow over more than one line causes a wrong linenumbering on the right side in my document.

Could anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong? The apparatus footnote displays the correct linenumber. I wasn't able to find the point and would be very glad, if someone has an idea. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[papersize={17cm, 24cm}, left=2.4cm, right=1.8cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=2.4cm,dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[C]{paragraph}



\sidenotemargin{right}
\eledsectnotoc{R}
\eledsectmark{L}


\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{latin}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsection*{Long Title that goes faaaaar beyond one line with a lot of text going on and on}
\pend\pstart
\blindtext[1]
\pend\pstart
A paragraph
\pend\pstart
\blindtext[1]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
\eledsection*{Ein langer Titel ohne Punkt und Komma und außerdem ganz viel Text}
\pend\pstart
\blindtext[1]
\pend\pstart
A \edtext{footnote}{\Afootnote{A remark.}}
\pend\pstart
\blindtext[1]
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, the wrong linenumbers are probably a bug. You could open an issue at [github](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues). Maïeul Rouquette is planning to rewrite the `\eledsection`-code [anyway](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/474) at some point in the future. In the meantime you can add manual linebreaks to the heading with `\newline` to correct the linenumbers.

Comment: It works if one add a bit more text. Imho relepar is measuring the length of the section title in \normalsize and so gets the number of lines wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That explains a lot to me and will probably solve a lot of problems in my text. I'll open an issue on github.

Comment: yeah, that is a big problem, alreeady knew. manul line breaking is for now the only one solution